# Wordpress media library don't load most of the photos in library

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, media-library, 404-error, dashboard

Whenever i try to load photos in the media library of my wordpress woocommerce site only the view at the top appear and the rest display "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404" at the browser console.[image: Here's a screenshot of the browser console and the media library.]

Comment: Images may not have proper path. Check the path of images.

Comment: It happen when images are not in your directory folder, check your directory.

Comment: Have you changed your site URL, such as switching to HTTPS?